# Error when trying to view Previous Version of a File in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, version-history

Whenever I try and access a file's version history in SharePoint Designer (2013 in this case), I get the following error:

`Versions cannot be accessed at this time server is busy`


This is a relatively quiet development server that maybe has 2 users at any time on it.  Nothing else seems to time out.  A quick check of Windows Application and SharePoint trace logs revealed nothing more telling.  Has anyone else seen this?  What I was trying to do is view an older version of a file for some comparision, is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: I was about to ask this question. I reckon it's a bug or something needs to be configured. In the meantime, you can of course access version history through the standard web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when I tried to Restore a previous version and spent 1/2 day troubleshooting.  Turns out the issue was a result of the "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" setting under Versioning Settings.  Because this was set to Yes, it required that the document be checked out before restoring it to a previous version.